# What is the problem with my Spigot 1.15.2 code?

Tags: java, minecraft

I just coded this and had no Errors in IntelliJ. I watched a tutorial about how to do it in 1.15.2. The first code is the error, the second the main.java and the third the PdInvCmd. Google don't know it too.  I don't know what to do about this, can you guys help me?  Btw: I'm new in spigot / paper coding, I'm sorry if the mistake I made is obvious.

```
Error occurred while enabling Rp-System v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:203) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at me.fafy.rp.cmds.PdInvCmd.<init>(PdInvCmd.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at me.fafy.rp.main.register(main.java:31) ~[?:?]
    at me.fafy.rp.main.onEnable(main.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:472) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:386) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:488) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:298) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:909) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:206) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at me.fafy.rp.main.<init>(main.java:8) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:80) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:137) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:397) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:305) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:360) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:234) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-391]
    ... 2 more
```

```
package me.fafy.rp;

import me.fafy.rp.cmds.*;
import me.fafy.rp.listener.PlayerDeathListener;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class main extends JavaPlugin {

    public static String pr = "§e§lMC-RP §7» ";

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Plugin geladen");
        this.register();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("Plugin entladen");
    }

    private void register() {
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("heal").setExecutor(new HealCmd());
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("md").setExecutor(new MdCmd());
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("pd").setExecutor(new CallPd());
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("help").setExecutor(new HelpCmd());
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerDeathListener(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginCommand("pdinv").setExecutor(new PdInvCmd());


    }



}
```

```
package me.fafy.rp.cmds;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PdInvCmd extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor {

public Inventory inv;

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if(player.hasPermission("rp.pdinv")) {


                inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "§c§lPD - Waffenschrank");

                // WAFFE 1 --------------

                ItemStack weapon1 = new ItemStack(Material.STICK);
                ItemMeta weapon1meta = weapon1.getItemMeta();
                weapon1.setItemMeta(weapon1meta);

                // DISPLAY NAME

                weapon1meta.setDisplayName("§bKarabiner");

                // LORE

                List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
                lore.add("§7§m --------------------");
                lore.add("§7 Keine Erweiterungen");
                lore.add("§7§m --------------------");

                // INVENTORY SET (inv.setitem)

                inv.setItem(10, weapon1);

            player.openInventory(inv);


        }



        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `PdInvCmd` extends `JavaPlugin`. That is not allowed, only the main class is allowed to extend `JavaPlugin`. Just remove the `extends JavaPlugin` from the `PdInvCmd` class and everything should work.